# How to manage generic collection in state in asp.netMvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls, generic-list

I am fetching the 200 records in List. It is user control under the shared directory in asp.net mvc 3.
I dont wat to fetch each redirection those records. so somehow i need to manage this List in state. i know there is no specific state management technic in the mvc 3. but how to manage this. my each page having this user control.
 As i am using the Azuresql it, charges to data transactions. to i am avoiding to use the "Session".
So please guide in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

> I know there is no specific state management technic in the mvc 3

Correct, there isn't any. One technique is to use [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.aspx) to avoid hitting the database on each request. This is valid only if the data is common to all users of your site. If not, Session is another alternative.

Comment: but what about the state of database ? suppose I have fetcehd the List<Users> onche , ok i kept in cache. but at server 10 more users added. then ?

Comment: @Red Swan, when you add users to the database you could expire the cache so that fresh data is fetched next time.

Comment: thats it , so i need to run back thread which always roundtrip for checking user added or not and then based on that i can clear my cache...is it right ?